# How to make three partitions?

Tags: partitioning

I have only Ubuntu operating system in my DOS system.

I have only one partition which is around 475 GB. I want to make three partitions of 150 GB, 100 GB, and the rest. How can I do that?

Comment: Use gparted from a live image (flash drive / CD).

Answer (score 0):

use gparted (as stated by @bodhi.zazen) to shrink your existing partition; then create the new partitions with newly-created available space.

the reason for using it 'live' is simplicity; its far safer to modify a partition whilst its not being used (your running ubuntu may have gparted installed; but the fs will be mounted; so a lot needs to be done to get it available-for-shrink. far easier, faster & safer to boot a live ubuntu (or other distro) & run gparted from usb|cd|dvd|..